# python-pexpect with telnet raises EOF exception

Tags: python, pexpect

I have a script which is trying to connect to a terminal server using telnet and passing a portnumber as parameter to access console. I have much success doing the same thing with Python CLI. But that success is not replicated with a script. Here is the output from the cli:

```
>>> import pexpect
>>> console = pexpect.spawn('/usr/bin/telnet k2dc-term1-kk2 6026')
>>> console
<pexpect.spawn object at 0x7fdc70dd3450>
>>> console.sendline('\n')
2
>>>>>> console.expect(['LOADER-A\*>'])
0
```

Now, when it comes to script:

```
import pexpect
import sys

console = pexpect.spawn('/usr/bin/telnet', ['k2dc-term1-kk7 6026'])

index = console.expect(['LOADER-A*>'])
```

The output I get is:

```
>./texpect.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./texpect.py", line 8, in <module>
    index = console.expect(['LOADER-A*>'])
  File "/usr/software/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 1354, in expect
    return self.expect_list(compiled_pattern_list, timeout, searchwindowsize)
  File "/usr/software/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 1368, in expect_list
    return self.expect_loop(searcher_re(pattern_list), timeout, searchwindowsize)
  File "/usr/software/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 1439, in expect_loop
    raise EOF (str(e) + '\n' + str(self))
pexpect.EOF: End Of File (EOF) in read_nonblocking(). Exception style platform.
<pexpect.spawn object at 0x7fd281666310>
version: 2.5.1
command: /usr/bin/telnet
args: ['/usr/bin/telnet', 'k2dc-term1-kk7 6026']
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: re.compile("LOADER-A*>")
buffer (last 100 chars):
before (last 100 chars): telnet: k2dc-term1-kk7 6026: Name or service not known

after: <class 'pexpect.EOF'>
match: None
match_index: None
exitstatus: 1
flag_eof: True
pid: 21520
child_fd: 3
closed: False
timeout: 30
delimiter: <class 'pexpect.EOF'>
logfile: None
logfile_read: None
logfile_send: None
maxread: 2000
ignorecase: False
searchwindowsize: None
delaybeforesend: 0.05
delayafterclose: 0.1
delayafterterminate: 0.1
```

Also I noticed, if I pass the terminal server and port number in a separate list, pexpect tries to connect to the terminal server only first. But I am wondering the difference between Python CLI and the script. If anybody cans shed some light on this, many thanks.